# Making code shorter

Tags: c

I'm currently building a program and I'm trying to make my code a bit shorter. It's just a for-loop repeating itself 15 times.
Can someone show me how they would do it and explain why they did like that.
any ideas?

```
for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=0;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][0]=counter;

    }

    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=1;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][1]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=2;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][2]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=3;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][3]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=4;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][4]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=5;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][5]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=6;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][6]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=7;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][7]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=8;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][8]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=9;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][9]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=10;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][10]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=11;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][11]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=12;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][12]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=13;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][13]=counter;

    }
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=14;

        if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
        {
            feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
            if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        table[i][14]=counter;

    }
```

Comment: You know, loops can be nested.

Comment: Have you heard of the refactoring method "extract method"? http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Comment: Does this code work? Looks like a closing curly brace is missing at the end.

Comment: yes it works i just took part of the full code because it's very long

Comment: This should be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com, it's not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 5):

You should do something like below, nesting the for loops.

```
for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
{
  for(int k=0; k<15; k++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
    {
      counter = 0;
      s[0]=0;
      s[4]=k;

      if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
      {
        feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
        if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
        {
          counter++;
        } 
      }
      table[i][0]=counter;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about **what** loops are for.

This is trivial to refactor, really. You have the exact same code repeating 16 times. So:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
    // your inner, repeating loop here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shorter version. Try it if you find it useful,

```
for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
{
    for (int k=0; k<15; ++k)
    {
        s[0]=0;
        s[4]=k;
        for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
            {
                feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
                if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            table[i][k]=counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he changes the value of s[4], typo?

Answer (score 2):

Without fully understanding what you're doing you can add another loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<1296; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 15; ++k) 
    {
        for (int j=0; j<1296; j++)
        {
            if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
            {
                counter = 0;
                s[0]=0;
                s[4]=k;

                feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
                if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            table[i][k]=counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, have you tried this,

```
    for (i=0; i<1296; i++)
    {
        for (k =0; k< 15; k++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<1296; j++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            s[0]=0;
            s[4]=k;

            if (remain[j][0]!=-1)
            {
                feed(poss[i], remain[j], f);
                if (f[0]==s[0] && f[4]==s[4])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            table[i][0]=counter;

        }
    }

}
```

Please, ignore the indentation. My point is nesting the loop in another one. Any reason that it should fail?

Comment: you forgot to use `k` s[4]=k